# using double pointer for char - what's the problem in the code?

Tags: c, string, pointers, realloc, strtok

```
char* scanString()
{
    char* str = NULL;
    char* temp = NULL;
    int  numOfChars = 0;
    char c = '0';
    while (c != '\n')
    {
        scanf("%c", &c);
        str = (char*)realloc(str, sizeof(char) * (numOfChars + 1));
        temp = str;
        if (str == NULL)
        {
            str = temp;
            return str;
        }
        str[numOfChars] = c;
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            str[numOfChars] = '\0';
        }
        numOfChars++;
    }
    return str;
}
int main()
{
    char** doublePointer = NULL;
    char* m = scanString();
    char* token = strtok(m, ",");
    int i = 0;
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        doublePointer = (char**)realloc(doublePointer, sizeof(char*) * (i+1));
        if (doublePointer)
            doublePointer[i] = (char*)realloc(doublePointer[i], strlen(token) + 1);
        strcpy(doublePointer[i], token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        i++;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++)
    {
        printf("%d: %s\n", k + 1, doublePointer[k]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

im trying to get a string like "option1,oprion2,option3" into array of strings and then put each option in its place at the array.
at the end i wanna print wach option in the order they were put.
what am I doing wrong?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: `realloc(doublePointer[i]` That is an issue as `doublePointer[i]` has not been initialised and can contain any garbage value. Why use `realloc` there? Just use `malloc`. If fixing that doesn't solve it then please update your question to explain what specific error or incorrect behaviour you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by replacing

```c
doublePointer[i] = (char*)realloc(doublePointer[i], strlen(token) + 1);
```

with a `malloc`. Credits to [kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003365/kaylum)!